# node.js/socket.io disappearing variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, socket.io

In my app I have the following:

```
client.on('test', function(req, fn) {
        var returnArr = [];
        redis.hkeys(req, function (err, replies) {
            replies.forEach(function(reply, i) {
                if (reply.indexOf('list.') > -1) {
                    redis.hgetall(reply.substring(5), function(err, r) {
                        returnArr.push({name:r['name'],index:i});
                        console.log(returnArr);
                    });
                }
            });
            console.log(returnArr);
        });
        console.log(returnArr);
    });
```

For some reason, the second and third logs contain a blank array even though the array is declared once at the beginnning of the event. Any ideas?

EDIT: Sorry, I changed the variable name when I posted it here without thinking. This happens when it's named anything.

Comment: Don't call your variable `return`.

Comment: I have amended the original question, when posting the question I amended the variable name without thinking. This happens regardless of its name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those redis calls are asynchronous. That's why you provide them with callbacks. The code won't work even if you fix the variable name for that reason.

To elaborate: the code in the callback to "hkeys" will be invoked when the data is available. The call will return immediately, however, so your array will have nothing in it at that point.

You cannot wrap asynchronous calls in a function and expect to return a value. It simply won't work.

Instead, the general pattern is to do exactly what the redis API (and virtually everything else in the node.js world; that's kind-of the whole point in fact): give your own function a callback argument to be invoked when appropriate. In your case, it'll be inside the "hgetall" callback that's the last one to be invoked. It should figure out that your results array has as many values in it as there are keys, and so it's time to call the callback passed in to your function.

(I should note that it's not clear what you're trying to do, given that the overall function appears to be a callback to something.)

Another approach would be to use some sort of "promise" pattern, though that's really just a restructuring of the same idea.

*edit* — the general pattern for an API with a callback would be something like this:

```
function yourAPI( param1, param2, callback ) {
  // ...
  some.asynchronousFunction( whatever, function( result ) {
    callback( result );
  }
}
```

Now in your case you're making *multiple* asynchronous service requests, and you'd need to figure out when it's time to invoke the callback. I think you'd probably want to iterate through the "replies" from the call to get the keys and extract the list of ones you want to fetch:

```
    redis.hkeys(req, function (err, replies) {
        var keys = [];
        replies.forEach(function(reply, i) {
            if (reply.indexOf('list.') > -1) {
                keys.push( reply.substring(5) );
            }
        });
        keys.forEach( function( key ) {
                redis.hgetall(key, function(err, r) {
                    returnArr.push({name:r['name'],index:i});

                    if (returnArr.length === keys.length) {
                      // all values ready
                      callback( returnArr );
                    }
                });

        });
```

Comment: How would you recommend doing the above?

Comment: @grsx I updated the answer.  I'm not exactly sure what it is you're trying to do; in other words, your question is clearly the result of your testing to determine what's going on, but it's not clear what you would do with "returnArr" eventually.

Comment: Basically, I need to return a list of items that are requested by the client from the redis store. Once that's been done I need to return all of the results as objects inside an array.

That array is then passed to the client to do whatever with.

Comment: OK, well you can't do that :-)  What you *can* do, however, is let the client provide a function to be called when the results are all collected.

Comment: Would you be able to give a quick example of that?

Comment: OK I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect. I was having one of those moments where you look at the code for so long that your mind goes blank!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call your variable `return`

It is one of a few reserved words that you cannot use in your code as variables.

Answer (score 1):

As Neal suggests don't use javascript reserved words for your variables, here is the list :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words

Answer (score 1):

@Pointy answered this tersely already, but let me explain it a bit more clearly: Those nested functions are not being run in the order you think they are.

Node.js is *non-blocking*, and uses Javascript's implicit event loop to execute them when ready. Here's your code with line numbers:

```
/*01*/ client.on('test', function(req, fn) {
/*02*/     var returnArr = [];
/*03*/     redis.hkeys(req, function (err, replies) {
/*04*/         replies.forEach(function(reply, i) {
/*05*/             if (reply.indexOf('list.') > -1) {
/*06*/                 redis.hgetall(reply.substring(5), function(err, r) {
/*07*/                     returnArr.push({name:r['name'],index:i});
/*08*/                     console.log(returnArr);
/*09*/                 });
/*10*/             }
/*11*/         });
/*12*/         console.log(returnArr);
/*13*/     });
/*14*/     console.log(returnArr);
/*15*/ });
/*16*/ //Any other code you have after this.
```

So, what's the order of execution of this thing?

Line 1: Register the event handler for the 'test' event.

Line 16: Start running any other code to be run during this pass through the event loop

Line 2: A 'test' event has been received at some point by the event loop and is now being handled, so `returnArr` is initialized

Line 3: A non-blocking IO request is performed, and a callback function is registered to execute when the proper event is queued into the event loop.

Line 14-15: The *last* `console.log` is executed and this function is finished running, which should end the current event being processed.

Line 4: The request event returns and the callback is executed. The `forEach` method is one of the few *blocking* Node.js methods with a callback, so every callback is executed on every reply.

Line 5: The `if` statement is executed and either ends (goes to line 10) or enters the block (goes to line 6)

Line 6: A non-blocking IO request is performed, adding a new event to the event loop and a new callback to be run when the event comes back.

Line 9: Finishes the registration of the callback.

Line 10: Finishes the `if` statement

Line 11: Finishes the `` `forEach `` callbacks.

Line 12: Executes the *second* `console.log` request, which still has nothing in the `returnArr`

Line 7: One of the events returns and fires the event handler. The `returnArr` is given the new data.

Line 8: The *first* `console.log` is executed. Depending on which event this is, the length of the array will be different. Also the order of the array elements **DOES NOT** have to match the order of the replies listed in the `replies` array.

Essentially, you can look at the more deeply nested functions as executing *after* the entirety of the less-deeply nested functions (because that's what's happening, essentially), regardless of whether the method contains statements after nested non-blocking callback or not.

If this is confusing to you, you can write your callback code in a [Continuation Passing Style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style) so it's obvious that everything in the outer function is executed before the inner function, or you can use [this nice async library](https://github.com/caolan/async) to make your code look more imperative.

This, I think, answers your real question, rather than the one you've entered.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. It's much appreciated. It does answer why the variable was empty but I've marked Pointy's as the answer as it contained a resolution. I would mark both if I could or vote yours up but I need 15 rep to vote it up.